# How to hide /profile Endpoint in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-rest

First time I'm  writing a Webservice and really I was able to hide my repositories with `@RestResource(exported = false)` but when I start my Service Application with the root uri like: `http://localhost:8080/api/` I can still see the following:
[image: Image showing Problem]

How can I hide  this from public view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like Hateoas response.

If you have any dependency for `spring-boot-starter-hateoas` or `spring-hateoas`, please remove them. This shall turn it off

If you are using spring-data-rest, then you may need to set spring boot as following:
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: Second one did it, thank you very much.